# Flex 4.5 - s:Group default margins?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe, flash-builder, flex4.5

The code below produces two groups with colored backgrounds and a margin between them. Ive tried the obvious css fixes (margin-top/bottom etc) but it seems it doesnt do any good. Does anyone know how i can do this?

```
    <s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
        <s:Group id="topBar" width="100%" height="10%" bottom="0">
            <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:fill><s:SolidColor color="black" /></s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>

        <s:Group id="contentBar" width="100%" height="90%" top="0">
            <s:Rect width="100%" height="100%">
                <s:fill><s:SolidColor color="red" /></s:fill>
            </s:Rect>
        </s:Group>
    </s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying you want to get rid of the gap between children elements of the VGroup?

You can set gap=0 in the group, as in:

```
<s:VGroup gap="0" />
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was completely off on that one.  Was sure the child elements were the culprit. Thanks!